# Is there need for correction of p-value for sub-ANOVAs conducted after significant four-way interaction in mixed rp ANOVA?

Tags: anova, interaction, multiple-comparisons

I found a significant four-way interaction in my mixed model 5-ways ANOVA (analysis of ERP data, 2*2*2*3*2).

My variables are:

- Within-subject factors: magnitude of outcome (big, small), likelihood
  of outcome(high, low), valence of outcome (gain, loss), electrode
  (Fz, Cz, Pz)
- Between-subject factors: group (group 1, group 2)

Interaction is
magnitude * likelihood * valence * electrode

I will try to disentangle this interaction by analysing factor levels of my data set separately, similar to https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/73064/132815

I have two questions regarding this process:

1. I wonder, whether there is need to correct for multiple comparisons, if I do more than 2 ANOVAs? For example, Bonferonni or FDR correction?
2. Naïve question: is there any special name for this kind of procedure?

Thanks in advance!